Outlook read calender working on Windows Business 11, but not windows 10
Below code, which is working well on my laptop but when using the same code on a machine windows 10 is does not work. Injection of new appointment works, but it does keep on booking double on same time again not in windows 11 Business.
To test it in outlook call it like (input date/time where you have an appointment)
Function calenderTest()
  'below should in return true if already booked
  msgbox(CheckAvailability("28/11/2024", "11:00", "20"))
End Function

Part that calls the function below
SlotIsTaken = True 
Do Until Not SlotIsTaken Or dtTimeToCheck > WorkendTime 
    SlotIsTaken = CheckAvailability(dtDateToCheck, dtTimeToCheck, TDuration) 
    If SlotIsTaken Then dtTimeToCheck = dtTimeToCheck + min_Duration_for_slot 
    ' Set the start time to the next available time slot. 
Loop 

Function:
Public Function CheckAvailability(ByVal argChkDate As Date, _
    ByVal argChkTime As Date, ByVal duration As Date) As Boolean


    Dim oApp As Object 'Outlook.Application
    Dim oNameSpace As Object 'Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oApptItem As Object 'Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim oFolder As Object 'Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As Object 'Outlook.meetingItem
    Dim oObject As Object
    Dim ItemstoCheck As Object 'Outlook.Items
    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim FilteredItemstoCheck As Object 'Outlook.Items
    Dim argCheckDate As Date
    Dim daStart As String
    Dim daEnd As Variant
   
    'Combine the date and time arguments
    argCheckDate = argChkDate + argChkTime

    'Avoid past booking of calendar
    If argCheckDate < Now Then
        CheckAvailability = True
        GoTo FUNCEXIT
    End If

    On Error Resume Next

    'Check if Outlook is running
    Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    If Err <> 0 Then
        'If not running, start it
        Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    End If
   
    'Get the default calendar folder
    Set oNameSpace = oApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oFolder = oNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
 
   'Get all items in the calendar folder
    Set ItemstoCheck = oFolder.Items
 
   'Include recurring appointments
    ItemstoCheck.IncludeRecurrences = True
 
   'Sort the items by start date
    ItemstoCheck.Sort "[Start]"

   

    'Filter the items by the given date range
    daStart = Format(argChkDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AMPM")
    daEnd = Format(argChkDate + 1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss AMPM")
    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & daStart & "' AND [End] <= '" & daEnd & "'"

    Set FilteredItemstoCheck = ItemstoCheck.Restrict(strRestriction)

    'Check if there is a conflicting appointment
    CheckAvailability = False
    For Each oObject In FilteredItemstoCheck
        If oObject.Class = olAppointment Or oObject.Class = olMeetingRequest Then

            Set oApptItem = oObject
            If (oObject.Start = argCheckDate) _
                Or oObject.End = (argCheckDate + duration) _
                Or (argCheckDate > oObject.Start And argCheckDate < oObject.End) _

                Or ((argCheckDate + duration) > oObject.Start And (argCheckDate + duration) < oObject.End) _

                Or oObject.Start > argCheckDate And oObject.Start < (argCheckDate + duration) Then

                    CheckAvailability = True
                    Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next oObject
 
FUNCEXIT:
    'Cleanup
    Set oApp = Nothing
    Set oNameSpace = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
End Function


Do you get an error if you comment out on error resume next?

Mis read Ill check that and come back m need to wait for tomorrow unfortunately

Edit the post. Add the code that calls the function and test data.

Please don't double-space code when posting - it makes it much harder to review, since there's so much more scrolling.

On Error Resume Next means you won't see any errors in your code.

On laptop no errors, and for windows 10 need to check that tomorrow.

On laptop no errors - possibly errors but with OERN how would you know?

commented out the On Error Resume and no errors.

Or oObject.Start > argCheckDate And oObject.Start < (argCheckDate + duration) Then don't you need a set of parentheses to group these two And'ed tests?

If I am not mistaken that is done with strRestriction you mean START END tags ?

No I mean Or (oObject.Start > argCheckDate And oObject.Start < (argCheckDate + duration)) Then  as you did for the two lines above this one.

See what you mean, will check that. And how would that make the dif between w11business and w10 ?

I wouldn't expect it to make any difference.  Your issue might be some kind of caching problem (?), assuming both PC's are accessing the same account and aren't set up identically...  I'm no expert on that though.

Offices run W10 (each office dif. account), ill add those. See if it will change anything for w11Business no change so... I suppose it be something stupid once I find it however research on web little luck so I though to ask the professionals

Misreading dates occurs frequently. Others may respond if you provide running code and sample data. How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. Start with Option Explicit.

Option Explicit and other small changes done, still no functionality in w10. (added small function which should return false / true. )

Your function has a parameter ByVal duration As Date and in your sample calenderTest call you pass "20" as an argument to that parameter. Is that supposed to be a number of minutes?  Format(CDate("20"),"YYYY-MM-DD is 1900-01-19

Yes that's the number of minutes, for which I tried duration as Long and duration = DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) Below code is functioning just not checking end time in Calender.

In Windows 10
' argCheckDate and hh:mm
daStart = Format(argCheckDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
daEnd = Format(argCheckDate + 1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")

Option Explicit

Sub calenderTest()
    'below should in return true if already booked
    MsgBox (CheckAvailability("28/11/2024", "11:00", "20"))
End Sub

Public Function CheckAvailability(ByVal argChkDate As Date, _
    ByVal argChkTime As Date, ByVal duration As Date) As Boolean
    
    ' duration As Date ?
    
    ' Since Outlook constants used, code is in Outlook
    ' olFolderCalendar, olAppointment and olMeetingRequest
    
    Dim oApptItem As AppointmentItem
    Dim oFolder As folder
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As MeetingItem
    Dim oObject As Object
    Dim ItemstoCheck As Items
    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim FilteredItemstoCheck As Items
    Dim argCheckDate As Date
    Dim daStart As String
    Dim daEnd As String
   
    'Combine the date and time arguments
    argCheckDate = argChkDate + argChkTime

    'Avoid past booking of calendar
    If argCheckDate < Now Then
        CheckAvailability = True
        GoTo FUNCEXIT
    End If
    
    'Get the default calendar folder
    Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
 
   'Get all items in the calendar folder
    Set ItemstoCheck = oFolder.Items
 
   'Include recurring appointments
    ItemstoCheck.IncludeRecurrences = True
 
   'Sort the items by start date
    ItemstoCheck.Sort "[Start]"

    'Filter the items by the given date range
    ' argCheckDate and hh:mm
    daStart = Format(argCheckDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
    daEnd = Format(argCheckDate + 1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
    
    ' If US date format fails when day is less than 13
    '  DDDDD HH:NN
    '  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm AM/PM
    
    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & daStart & "' AND [End] <= '" & daEnd & "'"
    
    Set FilteredItemstoCheck = ItemstoCheck.Restrict(strRestriction)
    
    'Check if there is a conflicting appointment
    CheckAvailability = False
    For Each oObject In FilteredItemstoCheck
        If oObject.Class = olAppointment Or oObject.Class = olMeetingRequest Then

            Set oApptItem = oObject
            If (oObject.Start = argCheckDate) _
              Or oObject.End = (argCheckDate + duration) _
              Or (argCheckDate > oObject.Start And argCheckDate < oObject.End) _
              Or ((argCheckDate + duration) > oObject.Start And (argCheckDate + duration) < oObject.End) _
              Or oObject.Start > argCheckDate And oObject.Start < (argCheckDate + duration) Then

                CheckAvailability = True
                Exit For
            End If
        End If

    Next oObject
    
End Function

If you need to know CreateObject was used from say Excel VBA. If the user did not have Outlook open, you can close Outlook.
Option Explicit

Sub getCreateOutlookfromOtherApplication()

Dim oApp As Object
Dim myFolder As Object
Dim isCreated As Boolean

'Check if Outlook is running
On Error Resume Next
Set oApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")

' Consider mandatory and as close as possible to On Error Resume Next
On Error GoTo 0

'If not running, start it
If oApp Is Nothing Then
    Set oApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    isCreated = True
End If

Set myFolder = oApp.session.GetDefaultFolder(6) ' olFolderInbox
myFolder.Display

' Close / Quit only if isCreated = True

End Sub


So problem was constants, duration as Date. You would suggest what? and thank you. Il give it a go

Removing ":ss" from the date format was sufficient to return "True". The only other change would be argCheckDate  rather than argChkDate in Format(argCheckDate,.... I ignored duration. Just know it is not a date.

Thanks niton it did indeed work and as you already said there is a problem with end date  time. seems only to respecting daStart, guess have some debugging to do to pass correctly the daEnd. Also thanks for other comments which gave me better understand of the above code.

You could post a new question about how to add time to daEnd.

Will try first see how far I get, could you give me a tip, so far I've changed duration to as Long and added duration = DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) with not so much results

Perhaps you want to replace argCheckDate + duration with DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate). To move through the calendar that would likely fit better in If SlotIsTaken Then dtTimeToCheck = dtTimeToCheck + min_Duration_for_slot.

Tried that and many others. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79237806/auto-calender-appointment-not-booking-correctly-does-respect-start-but-does-not New question it is.
