Auto calender appointment not booking correctly. Does respect start but does not look at End time
If you have an appointment on let's say 30-11 at 11h00 to 12h00 it will only look at 11h00 and adds the 20 default time and inserts a appointment at 11h20 to 11h40 instead of 12h00 to 12h20.
Debug print info
dtTimeToCheck: 15:00:00
[Start] >= '2024-12-06 12:00 ' AND [End] <= '2024-12-07 12:00 '

Start of function loop.
 argCheckDate....: 06-12-24 15:00:00

 argCheckDate.....: 06-12-24 15:00:00
 CheckAvailability: False
End of function loop.
Appointment time :06-12-24 at: 15:00:00
False
2024/12/06
 dtTimeToCheck: 15:00:00
[Start] >= '2024-12-06 12:00 ' AND [End] <= '2024-12-07 12:00 '

Start of function loop.
 argCheckDate....: 06-12-24 15:00:00

 argCheckDate.....: 06-12-24 15:00:00
 CheckAvailability: False
End of function loop.
Appointment time :06-12-24 at: 15:00:00
False

Have tried changing duration as long and even duration = DateAdd("n", duration, argChkTime) As well as suggestions by Nitton but wasn't unfortunately able to find a solution.
Option Explicit

' If already booked for that time (11h00 + 20 minutes) return true, and check 11h20 + 20...
Function testReverseDate()
    Dim sDate As Date
    Dim sTime As Date
    Dim sEmail As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim sLocation As String
    Dim sRemark As String
    sDate = "06-12-2024"
    sDate = Format(sDate, "yyyy,mm,dd")
    sTime = "15:00"
    sName = "Just A Name"
    sEmail = "anon@email.com"
    sLocation = "My Location"
    sRemark = "My Remark"
    Debug.Print (sDate)
    Call BlockNextFreeSlot(sDate, sName, sEmail, sLocation, sTime, sRemark)
End Function

Sub BlockNextFreeSlot(dtDateToCheck As Date, sName, _
  sEmail, strLocation, sTime, sRemark)
  ' Set the minimum duration for a time slot to 30 minutes.
  Dim min_Duration_for_slot As Long
  min_Duration_for_slot = 20 / (24 * 60)
  ' Get the end time for the work day from the UserForm.
  Dim WorkendTime As Date
  WorkendTime = "16:00"

  ' Get the duration of the appointment from the UserForm.
  Dim TDuration As Long

  TDuration = 20 / (24 * 60) ' Default duration is 20 minutes.
  ' If the appointment duration is less than the minimum slot duration, set it as the new minimum.
  If TDuration < min_Duration_for_slot Then min_Duration_for_slot = TDuration
  ' Get the start time of the appointment from the UserForm.
  Dim dtTimeToCheck As Date
  dtTimeToCheck = Format(sTime, "hh:mm")
  ' Check if the time slot is already taken, and if so, find the next available time slot.
  Dim SlotIsTaken As Boolean
  SlotIsTaken = True
  Do Until Not SlotIsTaken Or dtTimeToCheck > WorkendTime
    SlotIsTaken = CheckAvailability(dtDateToCheck, dtTimeToCheck + TDuration, TDuration)
    Debug.Print (SlotIsTaken)
    Debug.Print (dtDateToCheck & " " & dtTimeToCheck & " " & dtTimeToCheck + TDuration)
    If SlotIsTaken Then
        ' Set the start time to the next available time slot.
        dtTimeToCheck = DateAdd("n", min_Duration_for_slot, dtTimeToCheck)
    End If
  Loop
    If SlotIsTaken Then
            'No slots open, search next day
            dtTimeToCheck = DateAdd("n", min_Duration_for_slot, dtTimeToCheck)
            Debug.Print ("Time to Check: " & dtTimeToCheck)
            Debug.Print ("---------")
            Debug.Print ("Date to Check: " & dtDateToCheck)
            Debug.Print ("---------")
            NextDaySlot = True
        Call BlockNextFreeSlot(dtDateToCheck + 1, sName, sEmail, strLocation, sTime, sRemark)
    Else
        If dtTimeToCheck = sTime And NextDaySlot = False Then
            If CreateAppointment(dtDateToCheck, dtTimeToCheck, sEmail, sName, strLocation, sRemark) Then
                'Create appointement as requested on same day, at requested time
                Debug.Print "Appointment time :" & dtDateToCheck & " at: " & dtTimeToCheck
                
            End If
        Else
            'Create appointement but was resceduled slots taken, send email with rescedule
            If CreateAppointment(dtDateToCheck, dtTimeToCheck, sEmail, sName, strLocation, sRemark) Then
                Debug.Print "Appointment time :" & dtDateToCheck & " at: " & dtTimeToCheck
            End If
            Debug.Print dtTimeToCheck
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print ("if next day, send notification")
    Debug.Print (NextDaySlot)

End Sub

Public Function CheckAvailability(ByVal argChkDate As Date, _
    ByVal argChkTime As Date, ByVal duration As Date) As Boolean

    ' duration As Date ?
    ' Since Outlook constants used, code is in Outlook
    ' olFolderCalendar, olAppointment and olMeetingRequest

    Dim oApptItem As AppointmentItem
    Dim oFolder As Folder
    Dim oMeetingoApptItem As MeetingItem
    Dim oObject As Object
    Dim ItemstoCheck As Items
    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim FilteredItemstoCheck As Items
    Dim argCheckDate As Date
    Dim daStart As String
    Dim daEnd As String
   
    'Combine the date and time arguments
    argCheckDate = argChkDate + argChkTime
    duration = DateAdd("n", duration, argChkTime)
    'Avoid past booking of calendar
    If argCheckDate < Now Then
        CheckAvailability = True
        GoTo FUNCEXIT
    End If
    
    'Get the default calendar folder
    Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
   'Get all items in the calendar folder
    Set ItemstoCheck = oFolder.Items
   'Include recurring appointments
    ItemstoCheck.IncludeRecurrences = True
   'Sort the items by start date
    ItemstoCheck.Sort "[Start]"
    'Filter the items by the given date range
    ' argCheckDate and hh:mm
    daStart = Format(argCheckDate, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")
    daEnd = Format(argCheckDate + 1, "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm AMPM")

    ' If US date format fails when day is less than 13
    '  DDDDD HH:NN
    '  yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm AM/PM
    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & daStart & "' AND [End] <= '" & daEnd & "'"
    Debug.Print (strRestriction)
    Set FilteredItemstoCheck = ItemstoCheck.Restrict(strRestriction)
    'Check if there is a conflicting appointment
    CheckAvailability = False

    For Each oObject In FilteredItemstoCheck
            If (oObject.Start = argCheckDate) _
              Or oObject.End = (argCheckDate + duration) _
              Or (argCheckDate > oObject.Start And argCheckDate < oObject.End) _
              Or DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) > oObject.Start And DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) < oObject.End _
              Or oObject.Start > argCheckDate And oObject.Start < DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) Then

                CheckAvailability = True
                Exit For
            End If

    Next oObject
Debug.Print
Debug.Print " argCheckDate.....: " & argCheckDate
Debug.Print " CheckAvailability: " & CheckAvailability
Debug.Print "End of function loop."

FUNCEXIT:
    'Cleanup
    Set oMeetingoApptItem = Nothing
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oApptItem = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
End Function


You could also look at using GetFreeBusy - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79111888/invitees-meeting-availability/79112159#79112159 for example  Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.addressentry.getfreebusy

Thank you, will look at both. Now solved but still thanks for those links.

I see min_Duration_for_slot = 0 and TDuration = 0. The missing code for CreateAppointment should have been caught with Option Explicit.

I see dtDateToCheck = 2024-06-12

You could put sDate = Split(sDate, "-")(2) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(1) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(0) just before sDate = Format(sDate, "yyyy,mm,dd") if you prefer it over CDate(sDate).

I returned argChkDate to the filter.
Duration variables declared as Long not Date.
I broke the If statement into multiple parts to see what it did. You could apply DateAdd to the original single If.
Option Explicit

' If already booked for that time (11h00 + 20 minutes) return true, and check 11h20 + 20...
Sub testFreeslotCalender()
    'Call BlockNextFreeSlot("30-11-2024", "Names", "anon@email.com", "Location", "11:00", "My Remark")

    ' Date format in a string is unreliable
    '  Test with d less than 13 and m <> d
    Call BlockNextFreeSlot("2024-12-06", "Names", "anon@email.com", "Location", "11:00", "My Remark")
End Sub

Sub BlockNextFreeSlot(dtDateToCheck As Date, sName, sEmail, strLocation, sTime, sRemark)

    ' Set the minimum duration for a time slot to 30 minutes.    
    Dim min_Duration_for_slot As Long
    min_Duration_for_slot = 30
    
    ' Get the end time for the work day from the UserForm.
    Dim WorkendTime As Date
    WorkendTime = "16:00"
    
    Dim TDuration As Long
    TDuration = 20
    
    ' If the appointment duration is less than the minimum slot duration, set it as the new minimum.
    If TDuration < min_Duration_for_slot Then min_Duration_for_slot = TDuration
    
    ' Get the start time of the appointment from the UserForm.
    Dim dtTimeToCheck As Date
    dtTimeToCheck = Format(sTime, "hh:mm")
    Debug.Print " dtTimeToCheck: " & dtTimeToCheck
    
    ' Check if the time slot is already taken, and if so, find the next available time slot.
    Dim SlotIsTaken As Boolean
    SlotIsTaken = True
    
    Do Until Not SlotIsTaken Or dtTimeToCheck > WorkendTime
    
        Debug.Print " dtTimeToCheck: " & dtTimeToCheck
        
        SlotIsTaken = CheckAvailability(dtDateToCheck, dtTimeToCheck, TDuration)
        Debug.Print " SlotIsTaken: " & SlotIsTaken
        
        If SlotIsTaken Then
            ' Set the start time to the next available time slot.
            dtTimeToCheck = DateAdd("n", min_Duration_for_slot, dtTimeToCheck)
            Debug.Print " dtTimeToCheck: " & dtTimeToCheck
        End If
        
    Loop
  
    If SlotIsTaken Then
        Debug.Print ("....Busy")
    Else
        Debug.Print ("Creating an appointement")
        Debug.Print dtTimeToCheck
    End If

End Sub


Public Function CheckAvailability(ByVal argChkDate As Date, _
    ByVal argChkTime As Date, ByVal duration As Long) As Boolean

    Dim oFolder As folder
    Dim oObject As Object
    Dim ItemstoCheck As Items
    
    Dim strRestriction As String
    Dim FilteredItemstoCheck As Items
    
    Dim argCheckDate As Date
    
    Dim daStart As String
    Dim daEnd As String
    
    'Combine the date and time arguments
    argCheckDate = argChkDate + argChkTime
    
    'Avoid past booking of calendar
    If argCheckDate < Now Then
        CheckAvailability = True
        GoTo FUNCEXIT
    End If
    
    'Get the default calendar folder
    Set oFolder = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)
    
   'Get all items in the calendar folder
    Set ItemstoCheck = oFolder.Items
    
   'Include recurring appointments
    ItemstoCheck.IncludeRecurrences = True
    
   'Sort the items by start date
    ItemstoCheck.Sort "[Start]"
    
    'Filter the items for given day
    ' Note: returned to argChkDate
    daStart = Format(argChkDate, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm AMPM")
    daEnd = Format(argChkDate + 1, "yyyy/mm/dd hh:mm AMPM")

    strRestriction = "[Start] >= '" & daStart & "' AND [End] <= '" & daEnd & "'"
    Debug.Print strRestriction
    
    Set FilteredItemstoCheck = ItemstoCheck.Restrict(strRestriction)
    
    'Check if there is a conflicting appointment
    CheckAvailability = False
    
    Debug.Print
    Debug.Print "Start of function loop."
    Debug.Print " argCheckDate....: " & argCheckDate
    
    For Each oObject In FilteredItemstoCheck
        
        If oObject.Start = argCheckDate Then
            Debug.Print " oObject.Start...: " & oObject.Start
            Debug.Print " argCheckDate....: " & argCheckDate
            CheckAvailability = True
            Debug.Print "Condition 1"
            Exit For
        End If
        
        If oObject.End = (argCheckDate + duration) Then
            CheckAvailability = True
            Debug.Print "Condition 2"
            Exit For
        End If
        
        If argCheckDate > oObject.Start Then
            Debug.Print " oObject.Start...: " & oObject.Start
            Debug.Print " argCheckDate....: " & argCheckDate
                
            If argCheckDate < oObject.End Then
                Debug.Print " oObject.End.....: " & oObject.End
                Debug.Print " argCheckDate....: " & argCheckDate
                CheckAvailability = True
                Debug.Print "Condition 3"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
        If DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) > oObject.Start Then
            Debug.Print " (argCheckDate + duration): " & (argCheckDate + duration)
            Debug.Print " oObject.Start...: " & oObject.Start
            
            If DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) < oObject.End Then
                CheckAvailability = True
                Debug.Print "Condition 4"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
        If oObject.Start > argCheckDate Then
            If oObject.Start < DateAdd("n", duration, argCheckDate) Then
                CheckAvailability = True
                Debug.Print "Condition 5"
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
        
    Next oObject

Debug.Print
Debug.Print " argCheckDate.....: " & argCheckDate
Debug.Print " CheckAvailability: " & CheckAvailability
Debug.Print "End of function loop."

FUNCEXIT:
    'Cleanup
    Set oFolder = Nothing
    Set oObject = Nothing
    
End Function

Apparently the manipulated string is not recognized as a date.
' If already booked for that time (11h00 + 20 minutes) return true, and check 11h20 + 20...
Sub testFreeslotCalender_CDate()
    'Call BlockNextFreeSlot("30-11-2024", "Names", "anon@email.com", "Location", "11:00", "My Remark")
    ' Date format in a string is unreliable
    '  Test with d less than 13 and m <> d
    Dim sDate As String
    sDate = "06-12-2024"
    sDate = Split(sDate, "-")(2) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(1) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(0)
    Call BlockNextFreeSlot(CDate(sDate), "Names", "anon@email.com", "Location", "11:00", "My Remark")
End Sub


Thanks a lot, worked just fine, did noticed that you removed a few constants and was able to remove some lines after For Each . Did you have any particular reason for doing so. Also came to the conclusion that I've should broke up the if / or statement like you did it could of helped me find  my mistakes quicker. Was good for learning curve :) thanks for that as well.

I stand corrected, something is going very wrong. Do Until Not SlotIsTaken is not being called or correctly. And goes directly to If SlotIsTaken Then Debug.Print ("....Busy") which basicly should recall BlockNextFreeSlot  with dtDateToCheck +1 if it could find a free slot that day. Even then dtDateToCheck +1  seems not to be adding day + 1  correctly but inverses the day 06 12 (december) to 12 June.

Even with no Slots taken in that day, it should not say busy....  dtTimeToCheck: 3:20:00 PM  dtTimeToCheck: 3:20:00 PM  SlotIsTaken: True  dtTimeToCheck: 3:40:00 PM  dtTimeToCheck: 3:40:00 PM  SlotIsTaken: True  dtTimeToCheck: 4:00:00 PM  dtTimeToCheck: 4:00:00 PM  SlotIsTaken: True  dtTimeToCheck: 4:20:00 PM ....Busy

@Grmn Dates in strings can change to US date format when day <13. Try Call BlockNextFreeSlot("2024-12-06",

When adding Call BlockNextFreeSlot(dtDateToCheck + 1, sName, sEmail, strLocation, sTime, sRemark) to If SlotIsTaken Then it runs endlessly, with this as date dtTimeToCheck: 1/19/1900 11:00:00 AM and end with Out of Stack error

Since I am sending As Date to BlockNextFreeSlot is reason why it is going wrong. So guess i Need to send without formatting and figure out how to change 06-12-2024 to 2024-12-06 in vba.. Would this be a good way to go ? sDate = Split(sDate, "-")(2) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(1) & "/" & Split(sDate, "-")(0)

Apparently the manipulated string is not recognized as a date. Call BlockNextFreeSlot(CDate(sDate), ...

I've modified the code originally posted, again on w11 business, all good but on W10, it does not respect the time.
